# How Cacheing Works in Popular Android Apps for Infinite Scroll

Tags: android, facebook, caching, android-imageview, infinite-scroll

I am attempting to implement an "infinite" scroll type of feature in my app. The feature will display a list of items. Each item will contain images, text, etc. When the user scrolls down, more items will appear. I would like to know how "cacheing" algorithms works in popular apps and what is the recommended way to implement them.

The problem that I am having is that if the user visibly goes through 100 items, a lot of in-app Memory is used up. This causes the app to crash after seeing many items. I'm convinced that I should store some of these assets onto the File System of the phone and then re-use them once it's seen again. Please correct me if I am wrong.

For example:

1. Facebook

   - In the News Feed, as I scroll down, many "news items" contain images/videos/text. If I scroll through 20, everything looks great. As I scroll down quickly to the "bottom" of the news feed after >40 items, it appears to halt for a split second to "load" more items.
   - Then, when I scroll back up the news feed, it will display the previously viewed items fairly quickly. I guess my question is, are only a limited # of items cached in memory and most items cached on the file system?
   - How does it work? I assume when the user sees **new news feed items** , the app must "download" the assets from the Facebook Server. However, if these items become un-visible, and then the user scrolls back to these items, are these items re-downloaded, retrieved from memory cache, or retrieved from file cache?

Comment: Maybe its using sqlite for the data cache and image cache there is a lot of libraries out there. I'm also facing the issue to implement this kind of solution, but it seems not easy as I think...